# How to call an AsyncTask Activity from aBroadcast Receiver in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I am developing a sample app where I have an AsyncTask within a main Activity, I am also having broadcast receiver that listens for incoming sms.....

What i need to do is pass the message body from broadcast receiver to asynctask which is already listening for an incoming data using socket connection.
i don't know how to call the method defined in Asynctask from broadcast receiver.

Plz guide.

Answer (score 1):

read about AsyncTask this will be helpful

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
     protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
         //return str[0];
         return null; 
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

     }
 }

new MyTask().execute("MSG body");
```